# how to know HTTP Post upload complete while using HttpResponse in android

Tags: android

Hi iam writing a sample application where i need to select a image from gallery and upload the image to server using HTTP post.

my code is as shown

```
file = new File(mSelectedFileName);

Toast tt4 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in upload", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

tt4.show();

try {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

    InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(
            new FileInputStream(file), -1);
    reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
    reqEntity.setChunked(true); // Send in multiple parts if needed
    httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    //Do something with response...


} catch (Exception e) {
    // show error
    Toast tt2 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

    tt2.show();
}
```

here while upload is in progress i need to show a progress bar.
and once complete in need to stop the progress bar.
how can i get to know the upload is complete.

Answer (score 0):

You should use AsyncTask to do this because doing it on the UI thread is undesirable.  There are many examples of this just search [SO] for

> "[android] asyncTask progressbar http"

Here's an example I found on the web as an example [create-a-custom-progress-bar-using-asynctask](https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/create-a-custom-progress-bar-using-asynctask) which has more links to look at.  Also loads of exacmples on [SO]

Basically you just need to override the AsyncTask class.